# Change of variable with circle and ln

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I don't know how to solve:
$$\int \!\!\! \int_D x^3y^2 \ln (x^2+y^2) \, dxdy$$
over the area:
$$D=\{ (x,y): 4 \le x^2+y^2 \le 25, \,\, x,y \ge 0 \}$$

Obviously we are doing a double integration over the first quadrant of two circles, one with radius $2$ and one with radius 4.

I changed 
$$\left[
\begin{align}
dx\,dy=r\,dr\,d\theta\\
x=r \cos\theta\\
y=r \sin\theta\\
\end{align}
\right]
$$

Now we have:
$$ 2\leq r \leq 5$$
$$ 0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4} $$

$$\int\int_D (r\cos\theta)^3 (r\sin\theta)^2\ln (r^2) \ r \, dr\ d\theta$$

I replaced $\sin^2$ by  $1-\cos^2$

$$\int\int_D r^6 \cos^3\theta (1-\cos^2\theta) \ln (r^2) \, dr\, d\theta$$

$$\int\int_D r^6 \ \left(\cos^3\theta-\cos^5\theta)\right)\ln (r^2)\,dr\,d\theta$$

And after that I tried a double integration with the hope that I'll be back to $\cos^3-\cos^5$ after two cycles but $\ln(r^2)$ is crumping, so I am NOT getting anywhere with that technique. What shall I do?

Comment: If you prepend a backslash to trigonometric functions' names, LaTeX/MathJax will recognize them as special symbols and render in upright font with proper spacing: `2\sin\theta` → $2\sin\theta$ instead of `2 sin \theta` → $2 sin \theta$.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks for the tips, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is:$$\cos^3\theta\sin^2\theta=\cos\theta(1-\sin^2\theta)\sin^2\theta.$$Now, you can do the substitution $\sin\theta=u$ and $\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta=\mathrm du$.

Now, you have\begin{multline}\int_2^5\int_0^{\frac\pi2}r^6\cos\theta(\sin^2\theta-\sin^4\theta)\ln(r^2)\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta=\\=\left(\int_2^52r^6\ln r\,\mathrm dr\right)\left(\int_0^{\frac\pi2}(\sin^2\theta-\sin^4\theta)\cos\theta\,\mathrm d\theta\right).\end{multline}You can compute the first integral using the fact that$$\int r^n\ln(r)\,\mathrm dr=-\frac1{(n+1)^2}r^{n+1}+\frac1{n+1}r^{n+1}\ln(r).$$And, using the substitution that I mentioned above, the second one becomes$$\int_0^1u^2-u^4\,\mathrm du.$$

Comment: @Bernard Yes. It's pathetic. Thank you for the upvote.

Comment: I +oned. I couldn't understand why anyone would vote that down?

Comment: I can't get it right still. I come to $$\iint_D r^6 (u^2-u^4) \ 2 \ln(r) du dr$$. Shall I do partial integration now?

Comment: @Dovendyr I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks you a lot! Regarding $\int r^n \ln(r) dr$, I am not sure we went through that substitution at school, I will ask my teacher quickly.

Comment: @Dovendyr There's no substitution there. It's a formula that you can easily prove doing integration by parts.

Comment: Okej, it did an integration by parts and it's working swiftly. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Dovendyr I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Completing Jsé Carlos Santos' answer:

For the $\;\displaystyle\int r^6\ln r\,\mathrm dr$ part, proceed to an integration by parts.

More generally, it is good to know  integration by parts enables you to establish a recurrence relation between 
$$I_{p,q}=\int r^p \ln^q r\,\mathrm dr $$
and $I_{p,q-1}$.